# Move the "fun" questions to verbaloverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, questions, fun

That solves the badge gaming problem.

And yes the name is of course tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @cletus i think it's a good idea to create fun site - you just need a little more user-friendly title to sell it...

Comment: We can rename stackoverflow to seriousbusinessonlynofunallowed.com too.  It's a perfect solution.

Answer (score 7):

By moving them, they become less fun. :)

Comment: maybe what he means - create a place for a whole lot of fun?

Answer (score 2):

> All work and no play makes Jack a dull
>   boy.

Don't take the fun away. Consider also that many of the "Fun" questions are loosely tied to Programming/Technology, so not only does it offer a nice release from all of the so serious events throughout my day, it is still benefiting me in some sense.

Answer (score 2):

Create some fun outlet, see how it works. It may just exceed the expectations.

You can also have a tag there "too-serious".

Answer (score 1):

I think the fun questions are a very important part of SO (and SF and SU).

We have a problem on all three sites with questions being too zealously moderated (closing perfectly legitimate programming questions as not-programming-related because they're don't contain code, etc).

They generally mean well, but end up hurting the community (not to mention the poor souls just trying to get an answer).

Comment: Perhaps we can find the compulsive-obsessive users who are doing this and put them on their own site - maybe www.SeekTheFinalUpvote.com or STFU for short?

Comment: @MGOwen totally! lol :D

Answer (score 1):

The obvious name would be 'stackunderflow'; the implication being that you've run out of things to do, and need to waste time somehow.